# Alter column in BigQuery correcting typo

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery with a typo:

```
id,typo_column
1,Unknown
2,Unknown
3,Uknown
```

I want to replace `Uknown` by `Unknown`. Is there an easy way to do this in BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would normally do this as:

```
UPDATE yourproject.yourdatabase.yourtablewithtypo
    SET typo_column = 'Unknown'
    WHERE typo_column = 'Uknown';
```

There is no need to update every row in the table.  There is no need to use regular expressions, and there is no need to run logic for replacement on rows that don't have the incorrect value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DML to fix all entries with typos:

```
UPDATE yourproject.yourdatabase.yourtablewithtypo
SET typo_column = REGEXP_REPLACE(typo_column, r"(Uknown)", "Unknown")
WHERE TRUE
```

[See the docs for a more complete example.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-data#python)

Comment: @DavidMasip . . . Updating all rows in the table is generally not the preferred approach in any database, including BigQuery.